# How to remove a menu itme from menubar in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, menu, rcp

I am trying to remove "project" menu from menubar dynamically, means using code. Please help me out. It will be really helpful if someone can provide the exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing an RCP application you can control what goes into the main menu.  If you are adding plugins that you didn't write yourself and they are using extension points to contribute to the main menu, you can use Activities/Capabilities to remove them.

You cannot remove things from the main menu programmatically, unless your code contributed it.

Comment: We are using IWorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(String) to hide unwanted Menus from eclipse.ui plugins. We put the code in postStartup() method in ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor. I don't know if it's this you needed?

Comment: In your RCP app, that will work ... if you only offer one perspective.